# Как написать скрипт который выполняет другие скрипты по условию?

Tags: oracle, plsql, развертывание, sqlplus

Пытаюсь написать скрипт развертывания БД для запуска с SQL*Plus в CI/CD конвейере. Не могу найти способ выполнить скрипты по условию.

Вот сокращенная версия скрипта release.sql:

```
DECLARE
    val NUMBER;
BEGIN
    SELECT value INTO val
    FROM par WHERE name = 'version';
    IF val = 1.23 THEN -- run create scripts
        @ddl/da_001.sql
        @ddl/da_002.sql
        @dml/version.sql -- set initial version   
    END IF;
END;
/
```

Скрипт da_001.sql вглядит так:

```
CREATE TABLE TAB (
    COL1 NUMBER NOT NULL, 
    CONSTRAINT TABLE_NAME_PK PRIMARY KEY (COL1) ENABLE)
/
```

Когда запускаю:

```
sqlplus connection_string @release.sql
```

То получаю ошибку:

> CREATE TABLE TAB (
>
> - ERROR at line 7: ORA-06550: line 7, column 1: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "CREATE" when expecting one of the following: [...]

Ему не нравится `CREATE...` в начале, но не знаю почему. Чего здесь не хватает?

---

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [PL/SQL DB Deployment Script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63043069) от участника [@HasaniH](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7141/hasanih)</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/63043069

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я однажды уже прошел по этому <s>минному полю</s> полю с граблями...

Очень советую не полениться и установить [Liquibase](https://www.liquibase.org/) - очень мощный инструмент для релиз-менеджмента на стороне БД, который поддерживает накатывание SQL скриптов до определенного тега (версии) и откат скриптов (самая болезненная часть).

[Пример использования.](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/liquibase-automating-your-database-deployments)

PS [здесь можно найти альтернативы для Liquibase...](https://stackshare.io/liquibase/alternatives)

Comment: Мы все уже по граблям прошлись ;)

Comment: Вот [эту статейку](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/liquibase-automating-your-database-deployments) можно добавить как ссылку на вводную. Простого примера чтобы добавить в ответ там нет, но первые шаги доступно изложены.

Answer (score 2):

Создайте установочный скрипт, который запустит другие скрипты, например:

```
prompt START install.sql
@ddl/da_001.sql
@ddl/da_002.sql
@dml/version.sql
prompt Installed successfully
```

А затем вызывайте его по условию в  release.sql:

```
set feedback off pages 0
spool runme.sql
SELECT 
  case 
  when value = 1.23 then '@@install.sql' 
  else 'prompt Skipped install.sql' end
FROM par WHERE name = 'version'
/
spool off
@runme.sql
exit
```

Запуск и результат:

```
$ sqlplus -s -l connect_args @ release.sql
@@install.sql
start install.sql
Installed successfully
```

---

<sub>Свободный перевод [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63049484) от участника [@Connor McDonald](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7367293/connor-mcdonald)</sub>

Answer (score 2):

Решение с полностью динамическим созданием запускающего скрипта с аргументами для его отдельных скриптов в PL/SQL блоке:

```
set autoprint on 
set termout off
column sqls new_value sqls noprint 
var sqls varchar2 (4000);
declare
    val varchar2 (8);
    nl constant char (1) := chr (10);
begin
    select value into val
    from par where name = 'version';
    if val = 1.23 then 
        :sqls := 
            '@ddl/da_001.sql  arg1'||nl|| 
            '@ddl/da_002.sql  arg2'||nl||
            '@dml/version.sql arg3'||nl||
            'prompt Version '||val||' instaled successfully'||nl||
            'exit';
    else 
        :sqls := 'prompt Skipped due to version='||val; 
    end if;
end;
/
spool tmp.sql
prompt &sqls 
spool off
set termout on
@ tmp
```

Запуск и результат:

```
sqlplus -s -l connect_string @ release.sql
## executing da_001 arg1
## executing da_002 arg2
## executing version arg3
Version 1.23 instaled successfully
```